# Django Base Template Block Content not Rendered Correctly

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I am trying to have an fixed on top nav-bar and using only vanilla bootstrap. This required me to have a modification as the content needs to be padded in order for the page to render correctly.

Below is the form page it renders the Nav Bar on top but the content renders underneath the navbar instead of below it.

NOTE, that the base page itself works for other templates. What gives??

works(list Page):

```
{% extends 'expirations/index.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    {% for drug in drugs %}
    <div class = '.col-sm-12'>
        <ul class = 'list-group'>
            <li class = "list-group-item" >
              <span class = "badge">First Expiration: {{ drug.early_exp|date:"l M d Y" }}</span>
              <a href="{% url 'drug_detail' pk=drug.pk %}">{{ drug.name }}</a>
              {% regroup drug.expiration_dates.all by facility as facility_list %}
              {% for x in facility_list %}
              <span class="label label-info">{{ x.grouper }}</span>
              {% endfor %}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

doesn't work (form Page):

```
{% extends "expirations/index.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class = "container">
    <h1>Add Expiration for:</h1>
    <h4>{{drug_name.name}}</h4>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

index.html:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Expirations Tracker</title>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <!-- Optional theme -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

            {# Fonts#}
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Russo+One" rel="stylesheet">
            <!---DatePicker-->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <style>>
            body {
              padding-top: 100px;
            }
            @media (max-width: 979px) {
              body {
                padding-top: 0px;
              }
            }
            </style>
        </head>

    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navBar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand">Expirations</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navBar">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'drug_list' %}"><span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
             <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'drug_new' %}"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Drugs</a></li>
             <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'drug_exp_list'%}"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> List By Expirations</a></li>
             <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Facilities Serviced</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      </nav>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

         <script>
        $('#id_expirationDate').datepicker({
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              startView: 2,
              autoclose: true
        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe it's unrelated, but `.col-sm-12` should be `col-sm-12` (without the dot) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, both of them, the form and the list page, are rendering content underneath the nav bar.

However, there is a typo in your **index.html**:

```
<style>>
    body {
        padding-top: 100px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 979px) {
        body {
            padding-top: 0px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Remove the extra '>' after the `<style>` tag and it should work fine.

Comment: amazing how an extra ">" messes up your entire page haha, thank you very much! I have been staring at the code all day!

Comment: You're welcome! :) Could you mark the answer as the correct one? It would be very valuable for me and help me a lot.

Comment: How did you figure it out? I'm just curious lol I don't want to spend all day looking for that extra  < again

Comment: Thank you! Well, I was just lucky. I noticed that for the content not be underneath the nav bar it would be necessary to put a padding-top on the body. So, when I opened the index.html there was a padding already and it was not working.

Then I saw the extra '>' :)